# parsing JSON in nodejs

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

Hi i have the below json

```
{id:"12",data:"123556",details:{"name":"alan","age":"12"}}
```

i used the code below to parse

```
var chunk={id:"12",data:"123556",details:{"name":"alan","age":"12"}}
var jsonobj = JSON.parse(chunk);
console.log(jsonobj.details);
```

The output that i received is

```
{"name":"alan","age":"12"}
```

I need to get the individual strings from details say i should be able to parse and get the value of "name".I am stuck here any help will be much appreciated

Comment: Try chunk["details"]["name"]

Comment: You should quote it if you want to make it json. Otherwise its JS object literal

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you already have an object, you don't need to parse it.

```
var chunk={id:"12",data:"123556",details:{"name":"alan","age":"12"}};
// chunk is already an object!

console.log(chunk.details);
// => {"name":"alan","age":"12"}

console.log(chunk.details.name);
//=> "alan"
```

---

You only use `JSON.parse()` when dealing with an actual json `string`. For example:

```
var str = '{"foo": "bar"}';
console.log(str.foo);
//=> undefined

// parse str into an object
var obj = JSON.parse(str);

console.log(obj.foo);
//=> "bar"
```

See [json.org](http://www.json.org/js.html) for more details

Answer (score 1):

Since `jsonobj` has already been parsed as a JavaScript `Object`, `jsonobj.details.name` should be what you need.

Comment: `jsonobj` has be re-parsed. The whole parsing part can be skipped because `chunk` is already an object.

Comment: OK, I thought chunk was a string, otherwise parse make no sense.