# How to extract data from unknown json file?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

i have this json file :

> {
>       "moosy": {
>           "id": 39464441,
>           "name": "Moosy",
>           "profileIconId": 558,
>           "summonerLevel": 30,
>           "revisionDate": 1436887737000
>       }
>   }

Which is generated by an API.
Here is my code to get it :

```
var http = require('http');
var LolApi = require('leagueapi');
var summonerName = 'moosy';

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200);

      LolApi.init('MY_VERY_PRIVATE_KEY', 'euw');

      LolApi.Summoner.getByName(summonerName, function(err, summoner) {
          if(!err) {

            var profil = JSON.stringify(summoner);
            console.log(profil);
            res.write(profil);

            var summonerId = profil.summonerName.id;
            console.log(summonerId);
            res.write(summonerId);

          }
      })


});
server.listen(8080);
```

And i'd like to extract into different variables the ID, NAME, ProfileIconId and summonerLevel.

I haven't figured out how with JSON.parse, can you help me out ? :)
I'm using Node JS.

Thanks !

Comment: The syntax is invalid

Comment: if it is unknown you need to make it "known" before you post the question here

Comment: This question gets asks all the time

Comment: I'm using an api to get it, i'm editing the post to show you my whole code

Answer (score 0):

Go to http://jsonlint.com/ and validate your JSON. You will see that it is invalid. Maybe that is causing you troubles.

Answer (score 0):

Check the below post for an idea.

[Parsing json in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14208707/parsing-json-in-nodejs)

```
var summonerName = 'moosy';
var profil = { summonerName : { "id": 39464441, "name": "Moosy", "profileIconId": 558, "summonerLevel": 30, "revisionDate": 1436887737000 } };
ID=profil.summonerName.id;
NAME=profil.summonerName.name; 
ProfileIconId=profil.summonerName.profileIconId;
summonerLevel=profil.summonerName.summonerLevel;
```

Comment: Yeah but the thing is that "moosy" will change, it's an input, so i have a variable called summonerName where moosy is in, but it doens't work when i try ID=profil.summonerName.id;

Comment: Can you check my edit on first post ? I would like to retrieve these infos even if the player name change ('moosy' can be something else)?

Comment: ID=profil.summonerName.id; should work. can you post the JSON string again after the revised code with some other string.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to use a string variable (like `summonerName`) to access properties of an object, you need to use a different syntax.

Instead of doing this:

```
var summonerId = profil.summonerName.id;
```

Do this:

```
var summonerId = profil[summonerName].id;
```

The first way expects the object to literally have a property called "summonerName", which does not exist.