# how to parse some data from server response?

Tags: node.js, coinpayments-api

I'm new to nodejs. I now have a code like this.

```
var Coinpayments = require('coinpayments');

var cpayment = new Coinpayments({
  key: 'api',
  secret: 'api',
  autoIpn: true
});

var address = cpayment.getCallbackAddress("BTC", function (err, response) {

console.log(response);
})
```

which answers the bellow response :

```
{ address: '3Du1WGxRf1bPZXrX1EyhdAYB4g113RnDeY' }
```

But I need the answer just like this:

```
'3Du1WGxRf1bPZXrX1EyhdAYB4g113RnDeY'
```

can anyone help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [parsing JSON in nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14208707/parsing-json-in-nodejs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to access the value of the address key like this:

```
var Coinpayments = require('coinpayments');

var cpayment = new Coinpayments({
  key: 'api',
  secret: 'api',
  autoIpn: true
});

var address = cpayment.getCallbackAddress("BTC", function (err, response) {

console.log(response.address);
})
```